# where can I download my customized salesforce1 app?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've customized salesforce1 mobile app with the quickstart wizard in developer edition of salesforce, now I don't know where can I download it for smart phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mobile device's browser, open http://www.salesforce.com/mobile, and install the Salesforce1 application for your platform. The app is available for iPhone and Android.